# What ML Algo should I use to plot & predict customer location vs. amount spent?

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter

Im using real customer csv files from my ecommerce store. I was initially going to use k cluster with 2 values. I want the two values to be Province Code, and amount spend on my store. This will eventually show which region spends the most money at my store. However, the province codes are represented as 'CA, QC, UT, ... and you can't really use a string for a k cluster.

So was thinking of assigning a numerical value to each code and plotting it that way but I dont think that would make sense for k cluster. Any ideas on how i can implement ML another way? Ill provide a sample of my cleaned csv. I cant provide the original since it is illegal for me to give out customers addresses.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem most likely does not require a machine learning solution. If you are interested in the task, "given that a customer is from state X, predict how much the customer will spend", you can compute the median/mean of TotalSpent for each state. Consider plotting the result to display both variance and median/mean, e.g., by using a boxplot.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')  
sns.boxplot(data=df, x="Province Code", y="Total Spent")
```

Comment: Will do, thank you for your help. I still want to try and implement ml just for practice, do you have any ideas on how I can do that with customer data? I run my ecommerce store thru Shopify and their csv files basically just give me the customers contact and location so i can really only use their location and how much they spent, but if i had a third variable such as where they were referred (instagram, tiktok, google, etc) is there any shot of implementing machine learning? trying to get a project on my resume haha

Comment: @ChickenJoe If you're running an ecommerce store and looking for help with predicting sales, I suggest trying Cross Validated (the SE for statistics), or reading through a book on regressions. You probably don't want to use clustering for this task--clustering is for unsupervised learning rather than prediction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to frame your task first. Do you want to predict how much a customer would spend based on his location, referral channel, and some other variable you might have, or do you want to predict your sales for a given region in a given timeframe? That is, **step one** of your ML project is determining your target variable.

Once you define your problem, build a data set. I assume that would be somewhat easy for you as you can export a CSV from Shopify so you'd have some training data. Then, start simple with the modelling phase. If you are a beginner in ML, use "simple" algorithms like linear regression, decision trees, logistic regression, Naive Bayes, KNN (be aware that not all would be applicable to your problem - take your time to study each one carefully). You'll probably have some categorical variables (region, channel), so some pre-processing steps will need to be done. I'd recommend you to go through the documentation of [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html), it is beginner friendly but very powerful and valuable. There are a ton of [examples](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/index.html) for how to use the library.

In context of the answer from @etet above, I also think that you'd get more value from an in-depth exploratory analysis. Start off with that, then move on to ML.